# insertAdjacentHTML is not a function in svg element

Tags: javascript

I have some code where I want to insert some HTML on the click of the button. But when I click that button, I get the following error:

> TypeError: piecesLocation.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function

When inspecting the underlying code in the browser, I get this:

[image: Browser code on inspect]

The code that gets triggered when I click a button is this:

```
function showValues() {
const piecesLocation = document.getElementsByClassName('pieces');
piecesLocation.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<g class="values"></g>');
}
```

What is wrong with my code that causes it to trigger this error?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does not return one element. It returns an array like object. Either loop through the items, or specify an index `piecesLocation[0]`

Comment: That was the issue. I wasn't aware that it was an array that is returned. Thank you.

Comment: Be careful. It's not actually an array that's returned. So array methods like `map`, etc, are not defined on that object.